# FreeBSD Echoprint codegen

Tags: freebsd, audio-fingerprinting, codegen, echoprint

I am trying to compile Echoprint codegen on FreeBSD, but fail. But here's what i get when i try to run `make` or `make install`

```
> make
"Makefile", line 35: Missing dependency operator
"Makefile", line 39: Need an operator
"Makefile", line 41: Need an operator
"Makefile", line 50: warning: duplicate script for target "%.o" ignored
"Makefile", line 53: warning: duplicate script for target "%.o" ignored
"Makefile", line 56: warning: duplicate script for target "%.o" ignored
"Makefile", line 61: Missing dependency operator
"Makefile", line 62: warning: duplicate script for target "ifeq" ignored
"Makefile", line 62: warning: duplicate script for target "(,Darwin)" ignored
"Makefile", line 63: Need an operator
"Makefile", line 77: Missing dependency operator
"Makefile", line 78: warning: duplicate script for target "ifeq" ignored
"Makefile", line 78: warning: duplicate script for target "(,Darwin)" ignored
"Makefile", line 79: warning: duplicate script for target "ifeq" ignored
"Makefile", line 79: warning: duplicate script for target "(,Darwin)" ignored
"Makefile", line 80: warning: duplicate script for target "ifeq" ignored
"Makefile", line 80: warning: duplicate script for target "(,Darwin)" ignored
"Makefile", line 81: Need an operator
"Makefile", line 85: Need an operator
```

I tried running it as a root, and as a normal user. Both to no avail.

Unfortunately, i know nothing about makefiles. Is there a makefile for FreeBSD?

Best regards, 
Timofey

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install the `devel/gmake` port and use `gmake` instead of `make`.